# Rails 4 ActiveRecord associations: updating collectionproxy via Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

Trying to understand how to do this via Rails console.

Subscription - has many categories
Category - belongs to subscription

There were 9 categories, but I need to add a tenth.

If they were subscribed to the #9 category, I want them to already be subscribed to the #10 category when adding it. So it'll be something like:

```
subs = Subscription.all
subs.each do |sub|
  if sub.categories.where(name: "Category Number One").exists?
    puts "it does indeed exist." #update this line to add "Category Number 2" to sub.categories  
  else
    puts "it does NOT exist."
  end
end
```

I'm a bit confused on what to do with the `if` block. Seems like there is a method for what I want to do (note that category_ids is an `Array`):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-3C-3C

What would I pass in exactly though?

If I try with the actual category ID using `sub.categorizations << 10`, I get:

`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Categorization(#70215789049700) expected, got Fixnum(#70215753183840)`

Any insight on how to attack this problem the right way would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

create via

> sub.categories.create(name: "Category Number 2")

Comment: I'd suggest to do it with a `ActiveRecord::Transaction`, since he wants some of them to subscribe to this category while creating it

Comment: Ah, sorry, maybe I mispoke. Category 10 ALREADY exists before updating these subscriptions). I tried this: `sub.categorizations << Categorization.where(category_id: 10)` but it added category #10 twice. Why would that be?

Comment: b/c your schema is wrong. you wanted to have something like Subscription has_many :subscription_categories, which would be just a join table to Categories.

Comment: Schema isn't wrong. Join table is categorizations which has category_id and subscription_id. Used this and worked out well: https://gist.github.com/ornerymoose/7347a300ca599c6f47b1e6afe0c00a31 . Will upvote your answer as you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: fair enough. I wasn't sure what categorizations was supposed to be - the post is a little vague on the models. I'll edit your answer for style then.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new `Categorization` with the subscriber's ID   was the way to go. Also, lets not visit all the subscriptions, only the ones we need to change, and lets visit them in batches to minimize memory usage.

```
cat1 = Category.where(:name: "Category One").first!
Subscription.joins(:categorizations).where(:categorizations=>{:category_id=>cat1.id).find_each do |sub|
    sub.categorizations.create(category_id: 10)
end
```

Comment: Of course, one problem with visiting every sub like this is that you'll have a N+1 database problem. Better would be 1)  fetch only the records you need 2) batch them